# What are Channel and Signature in the Push API?

Tags: pubnub

In reference to [HTTP REST Push API](https://www.pubnub.com/http-rest-push-api/), my assumption is that I can literally replace the "Publish Test" URL (http://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/demo/demo/0/hello_world/0/%22Hello%20World%22) with data from one of my pubnub apps and put it in a browser.  I did this, replacing the "demo" strings with my pub and sub keys.  I got a JSON response of "Sent" with a unique ID.  However, when I look at the demo keyset that I used in my account, it says "0 messages".

1. What are Channel and Signature (0's in the URL above)? Do I need them? Where do I get them?
2. Would the above test register a message count in my demo key?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub Admin Dashboard Usage

The usage is computed once every 24 hours and posted to your account around 9am Pacific Time.

## PubNub REST API

For the publish REST call, the `0` parameters are `signature` and `callback` (not `channel` as you had indicated - assuming you meant `callback`, though):

```
http://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish
/pub-key
/sub-key
/signature
/channel
/callback
/message
```

And the example, that was provided (showing for everyone else):

```
http://pubsub.pubnub.com
/publish
/demo
/demo
/0
/hello_world
/0
/%22Hello%20World%22
```

The `signature` (the first `0`) was deprecated over 3 years ago so it should always be `0`. The `callback` would just be the name of the function that should be invoked for the `publish` response. The PubNub SDKs use this so `0` is appropriate for most non-SDK use cases.

Here is a more detailed `publish` REST documentation:

`https://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/{pub_key}/{sub_key}/0/{channel}/{callback}/{payload}{?store}`

**URI Parameters**

```
Name          Type          Required          Description
pub_key       string        Yes               your publish key
sub_key       string        Yes               your subscribe key
channel       string        Yes               channel to publish the message to
callback      string        Yes               response will be wrapped in JSONP function, 0 for no JSONP
payload       string        Yes               message to send (url-encoded JSON)
store         number        No                overrides default account configuration on message saving. store: 1, do not store: 0
auth          string        No                if the channel is protected by Access Manager (requires a permissions to be granted), auth must be passed with an auth-key which is authorized to write to the channel.
```

Comment: Good to know. Is there any way to confirm it's working without a subscription set up yet?  This also still doesn't answer what the other two path variables are.

Comment: I did confirm I see "1 message" now though.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Where did that `URI Parameters` table come from and why doesn't it include `signature`?